# Xfce4 make "Super" and "Super + D" working at the same time in a Windows manner

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, xubuntu, shortcut-keys, xfce

I have created shortcut for `Super` to open Whisker Menu.
But at the same time I want to create shortcut to show desktop with `Super + D`. (I would like to have it as in windows).

At current state only the `Super` is working for opening the Whisker Menu. (Ignoring the D key).

Also the `Super` key is opening the Whisker Menu immediately. Windows opens start menu only after  the `Super` is released. Is it possible to copy this behavior?

Comment: You can try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/51452/windows-like-global-shortcuts-with-the-super-key-in-xubuntu#790281

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: [Windows-like global shortcuts with the <Super> key in Xubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51452/windows-like-global-shortcuts-with-the-super-key-in-xubuntu)

Basically install ksuperkey, bind your menu to "alt+f1" and your done. Superkey will open the menu and Super + D, Super + E etc... will work as one would expect.

Comment: I have tried this and have failed.

Comment: did you start ksuperkey? What system do you use?

Comment: Yes, installed and launched. I have Xubuntu 18.04.