# Whisker menu windows key - too fast for lock?

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, whisker

I have the Windows key bound to open the Whisker menu in XFCE. Works great. I also use the Windows key to lock the screen like Windows: Win+L.

The problem is, if I hit Win+L ask quickly as I do on Windows, the Whisker menu pops up and then locks the screen. If I slow down and hold the Win key and press L, then it locks the screen without Whisker popping up.

Is there an adjustment somewhere to make this behave like Windows? Not sure if the response to the Win key needs to be slowed down or something for the Whisker menu.

Xubuntu 16.04.03,

Comment: You can try this https://askubuntu.com/questions/51452/windows-like-global-shortcuts-with-the-super-key-in-xubuntu#790281

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much! I installed it with this: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mehanik/ksuperkey && sudo apt-get update && sudo install ksuperkey. Added it to the autostart, then bound the menu key to Alt+F1. All good in the neighborhood!